# Is there a closed-form solution to the free evolution of a delta-function via de-Broglie waves?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, dirac-delta-distributions

One of the most fascinating parts of de Broglie's thesis is that, if you have a "hyperplane" wave in spacetime, with a frequency of $\omega_0$ and no spatial dependence in its "rest" frame, for example

$$e^{i\omega_0 t}$$

then in another frame, due to relativistic transformation, it will have a finite wavelength and finite but superluminal propagation speed.  Then, if you superimpose a family of such waves with different rest frames, but each with the same period in its own rest frame, they can form a wave packet whose group velocity is now subluminal.

Using special relativity, we can derive the phase velocity of a single hyperplane wave, in terms of the spatial wave vector.  I got

$$\mathbf{v}_p(\mathbf{k}) = \sqrt{c^2 + (\frac{\omega_0}{k})^2}\ \hat{\mathbf k}$$

where $\omega_0$ is still the rest-frame frequency.  Now, suppose we have a superposition of such waves which at $t = 0$ is a $\delta$-function.  Ignoring normalization,

$$\psi(\mathbf{x}, 0) = \int_{\mathbf{k}}{e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}}\,d\mathbf{k}$$

Allowing each de-Broglie hyperplane component to propagate at its phase velocity, we then have

$$\psi(\mathbf{x}, t) = \int_{\mathbf{k}}{e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{v}_p(\mathbf{k}) t)}}\,d\mathbf{k}$$

Then we can insert the above formula for $\mathbf{v}_p(\mathbf{k})$.  Is it then possible to evaluate this integral in closed form?

A related question is whether, after multiplying the solution by an arbitrary Dirac spinor, this is equivalent to solving the Dirac equation?  I don't think it would match the Schrodinger equation since that is non-relativistic...

I also wonder if it would be easier to solve if we assumed uniform distribution of 4D wave vectors in spacetime (i.e. equal probability of having any rest frame), rather than uniform distribution of $\mathbf{k}$ vectors as the $\delta$-function assumes.  But I'm not sure how you would set that up.

Comment: It would be Klein-Gordon, at most, not Dirac.

Answer (score 1):

The wave $Exp[I \omega t] $,  by inspection, is a  rotation on the unit circle,  the complex unit circle all over the world in a special coordinate system, where along the space axes the phase is constant. It has the four vector $(\omega, 0)$ and so it solves the wave equation
$1/c^2 \partial_{t,t} \psi -\Delta \psi = - \omega^2/c^2\psi $.

Somebody must have forgotten it there, rotating all the time when HE created space time manifold from begin to end of all times. It looks for HIm like the plane waves on the ocean with time direction orthogonal to the wave front.

Ok, that was the common work of Galilei, Descartes and Newton and this rolling everywhere synchonous phased obeject is nothing else but  Newtons and Kants ideda of the universal time ticking as a countinously distibuted system of clocks with dynamical connection to nothing,  synchronized with signals of infinite velocity.

With a signal phase velocity c being infinite, the wave equation

$1/c^2 \partial_{t,t} \Phi - \Delta \Phi=0$

has this special solution with the effect, that a slowly moving observer sees at each point of his travel the same time as his twin at home. The invariance group of these systems is the Galilei group

$t\to t', x \to x' + v t'$

and the time system ticks for the moving observe like  $Exp(\omega t')$ with the same time as the obseerver at rest.